# ERD diagram for non-relational database?

Tags: mysql, diagramming, erd, nosql

As we know ERD diagram is very useful for relational databases. 
Which Diagram is relevant for Non relational database ? can ERD be also used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on it:

If there are entities you need to define relations on, ***you can still use ER Diagrams for the sake of documentation.***

The choice of using a non-relational might be an *implementation detail*,then.

Answer (score -1):

Use Case, Class, Structure, Collaboration, Sequence etc. Currently using all of those diagrams for my Java games development project. Hope that helped! Good luck

Comment: UML has nothing to do with database so it's irrelevant.